# Dados retornados do PHP não aparecem no calendário do FullCallendar

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

Estou tentado listar em um calendário (em forma de eventos), implementado com o FullCallendar, dados resultantes de uma consulta ao banco de dados. O calendário aparece, só que os eventos que deveriam estar listados nele, não. Não sei onde posso estar errando. Vou deixar os códigos utilizados para vocês visualizarem:

**Código JS:**

```js
//BIBLIOTECA FULLCALLENDAR
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    height: 600,
    locale: 'pt-br', //Adicionando o idioma pt-br 
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
    editable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
    },

    navLinks: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    events: {
      url: '../banco/banco-get/pagina-dashboard/classes-dashboard-calendario.php', //Página PHP que realiza a consulta
      failure: function() {
        document.getElementById('script-warning').style.display = 'block'
      }
    },
    //Para eliminar o cache
    extraParams: function() {
      return {
        cachebuster: new Date().valueOf()
      };
    },
    eventClick: function(info) {

      info.jsEvent.preventDefault();

      //Passando valores para os elementos HTML   
      $('#visualizar #mostrar-titulo').text(info.event.title);
      $('#visualizar #mostrar-inicio').text(info.event.start.toLocaleString());
      $('#visualizar #mostrar-fim').text(info.event.end.toLocaleString());
      $('#visualizar #mostrar-fim').text(info.event.tipo);

      //Exibe o modal com (que pode ter as informações do evento do calendario)
      $('#visualizar').modal('show');

    },
    loading: function(bool) {
      document.getElementById('loading').style.display = bool ? 'block' : 'none';

    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
/* FIM DO FULLCALENDAR */
```

**Código PHP:**

```html
<?php

session_start(); 

require_once("../../conect/conexao.php");
  
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+3');
setlocale(LC_ALL, "", "pt_BR.utf-8");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

//Pegando o usuário logado
$usuario_logado = $_SESSION['nome'];  
  
    
class Agendador
{    
  private $usuario;

  public function __get($atributo)
  {   
    return $this->$atributo;
  }

  public function __set($atributo, $valor)
  {   
    $this->$atributo = $valor;
  }  

  public function listarAgendamentos()
  { 
    try
    {   
      //Conexão com o Banco de Dados 
      $c = new Conexao();
      $conexao = $c->conectar();

      $query = "SELECT CONCAT(tipo_atividade , ' (', COUNT(tipo_atividade) , ')') AS title , DATE_FORMAT(dt_vencimento , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS start, DATE_FORMAT(dt_vencimento , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS end, EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM AS tipo, STATUS ";
      $query .= "FROM tbl_atividades WHERE (STATUS <> 'CONCLUIDO' AND STATUS <> 'CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO') AND responsavel = :usuario ";
      $query .= "GROUP BY tipo_atividade, dt_vencimento";

      $stmt = $conexao->prepare($query);
      $stmt->bindValue(':usuario',$this->__get('usuario'));
      $stmt->execute();

      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      $i = 0;
      foreach($result as $key => $value)
      { 
        foreach($value as $key => $valor)
        {            
          if($key == "STATUS")
          {
            if($valor === "PENDENTE")
            {
              $cor = "#00BFFF";
            }
            else if($valor === "VENCIDO")
            {
              $cor = "#FF0000";
            }
            else if($valor === "INICIADO")
            {
              $cor = "#3CB371";
            }
            else if($valor === "INICIADO_VENCIDO")
            {
              $cor = "#FF8C00";
            }
            else if($valor === "STAND_BY_CLIENTE")
            {
              $cor = "#808080";
            }
            else if($valor === "STAND_BY_INTERNO")
            {
              $cor = "#808080";
            }       
          }     
        }     
        $result[$i]['color'] = $cor;
        $i++;
      }   

      echo json_encode($result);   

    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
      //Verificando o erro ocorrido
      echo "Erro: ".$e->getCode()." Mensagem: ".$e->getMessage();    
    }
  }    
}
 
//Classe Agendador
$agendador = new Agendador();
$agendador->__set('usuario',$usuario_logado);
$agendador->listarAgendamentos();
  
?>
```

**PRINT_R do resultado da Consulta no MySQL: (Está saindo perfeito)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS 1:** Não postei o código HTML para a pergunta não ficar muito grande e também porque eu acho que não tem muita necessidade. Os arquivos do FullCallendar estão sendo chamados corretamente, e o id da DIV é "calendar".

**OBS 2:** O JSON de retorno está saindo corretamente do PHP (Com isso já eliminamos a chance da query estar errada). Já fiz o teste. Mas quando dou uma console.log nele no JavaScript e sai nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Consegui resolver:**

O erro está no trecho abaixo:

```html
<?php
 
  $query = "SELECT CONCAT(tipo_atividade , ' (', COUNT(tipo_atividade) , ')') AS title , DATE_FORMAT(dt_vencimento , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS start, DATE_FORMAT(dt_vencimento , '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS end, EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM AS tipo, STATUS ";
  $query .= "FROM tbl_atividades WHERE (STATUS <> 'CONCLUIDO' AND STATUS <> 'CONCLUIDO_VENCIDO') AND responsavel = :usuario ";
  $query .= "GROUP BY tipo_atividade, dt_vencimento";
      
?>
```

- O FullCallendar não aceita retorno do PHP que tenha data no nosso formato (d-m-Y). Então, o correto é deixar no formato da gringolândia (Y-m-d) conforme abaixo.
- Depois de retornado os dados no PHP, lá no retorno do FullCallendar, no JavaScript, nós podemos converter essa data com o **locale:'pt-br'** e o **toLocaleString()**.

```html
<?php
  
  $query = "SELECT CONCAT(tipo_atividade , ' (', COUNT(tipo_atividade) , ')') AS title , DATE_FORMAT(dt_vencimento , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS start, DATE_FORMAT(dt_vencimento , '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AS end, EXTRA_URGENTE_COMUM AS tipo, STATUS ";

?>
```